# Cannot Change the AppBarLayout Margin Programatically

Tags: android, android-appbarlayout

I want to change my AppBarLayout Margin. But it is producing this error

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$LayoutParams
                                                                              at sstechnology.com.jiprasticks.Stickers.setMarg(Stickers.java:201)
```

Here is the code,

```
AppBarLayout appBarLayout;
appBarLayout=(AppBarLayout)findViewById(R.id.appBarLayout);
setMarg(0);
```

Code for setMarg(),

```
public void setMarg(int m)
{
    AppBarLayout.LayoutParams params=(AppBarLayout.LayoutParams)appBarLayout.getLayoutParams();
    params.setMargins(0,0,0,m);
    appBarLayout.setLayoutParams(params);

}
```

Here is the XML code for appBarLayout,

```
 <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff">
```

Comment: LayoutParams is WHERE the view (or viewgroup in your case) located. Make it ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams params=(ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams)appBarLayout.getLayoutParams();

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I did it myself by changing.  AppBarLayout.MarginLayoutParams params=(AppBarLayout.MarginLayoutParams)appBarLayout.getLayoutParams(); instead of              
AppBarLayout.LayoutParams params=(AppBarLayout.LayoutParams)appBarLayout.getLayoutParams();